# Elm: Get window-width on load

Tags: css, frontend, elm

So I am doing a pretty basic landing page in Elm and I want to determine what picture to use depending on the initial screen size and then again on resize. I found the resize function on the Window module, and made it work fine, but I couldn't figure out how to do it on load as well.

I am looking for something like:

```elm
initialModel : Model
initalModel model =
    {width = Window.size.width}
```

I have ended up making the picture as background-image on a div and then changing the picture depending on screen size, but it just feels less than ideal. Is the next best way to use elm-css?
Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To obtain a value at app load time, you will probably want to use [`Html.programWithFlags`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Platform#programWithFlags) and pass the window size in from Javascript.

```elm
type alias Flags =
    { windowWidth : Int }

type alias Model =
    { windowWidth : Int, ... }

main =
    Html.programWithFlags
        { init = init
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = \_ -> Sub.none
        , view = view
        }

init : Flags -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init flags =
    { windowWidth = flags.windowWidth } ! []
```

You pass in flags on app startup like so:

```js
var app = Elm.Main.fullscreen({ windowWidth: window.innerWidth })
```

Comment: Amazing, you just saved my day. Even though I am looking forward to less interop between the javascript part with Flags and Ports

Answer (score 7):

You can do this without javascript, using [elm-lang/window](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/window/latest/Window).

Start by importing `Window` and `Task`

You will need a Msg like so:

```
type Msg
  = SetWindowSize Window.Size
```

Then you just initialize your program with:

```
Html.program
  { init = ( [model], Task.perform SetWindowSize Window.size )
    ...
  }
```

This will get the initial size of the window.

If you want to continuously track window size changes, you need to subscribe to `Window.resizes`

Comment: For Elm 0.19 you want to look at using [Browser.Events](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser-Events)